# Erro SERVER_ADDR no PHP

Tags: php

Alguém sabe alguma solução para esse erro

```
Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_ADDR in C:\certificado\config.php on line 10
```

A linha a qual ele se refere é :

```
$desenvIp = ($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] == "::1") ? "::1" : "127.0.0.1";
```

Estou utilizando o PHP 7

Comment: Conforme [documentação oficial](http://ca3.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.server-description): "*Não há garantia que cada servidor web proverá algum destes; servidores podem omitir alguns*". Por que precisa desse valor?

Comment: Utilizo em dois casos de `if`, para realizar a configuração da pasta raiz do sistema, por explemo:
`if ($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] == $desenvIp)

 $files['rootSys'] = "/certificado/";
else if ($_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"] == $webIp)

 $files['rootSys'] = "/certificado/"; `

Comment: Então basicamente você usa apenas para identificar o ambiente, então por que não utilizar uma variável de ambiente?

Comment: Entendo, mas por exemplo, tenho que realizar a definição de uma URL para diferenciar as urls de produção das de desenvolvimento.Segue :


`if ($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == $webIp) {
 define("URL_SISTEMA", $url['producao']);
 define("URL_SITE", $url['producao_site']);
 define("URL_SITE_TPL", $url['producao_site_template']);
}
else {
 define("URL_SISTEMA", $url['desenvolvimento']);
 define("URL_SITE", $url['desenvolvimento_site']);
 define("URL_SITE_TPL", $url['desenvolvimento_site']);
} `

Em que esse webIP se trata do ip da maquina de produção, como fazer com variáveis ambiente ?

Comment: Como seria possível realizar essa comparação com uma variável ambiente, para realizar essa comparação ?